# Считать страницу и создать файл

Tags: php

Holo, нужно считать из default page(Шаблонной страницы) и создать файл этой же страницы в другой директории. Буду благодарен, сам пытался решить данную проблему, но вышло. Вот вам говнокод(быдлокод):

```
<?php
$file = "pages/".$row['name'];
$str = htmlentities(file_get_contents("defaultpage.php"));
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: учиться-учиться-учиться.

Comment: А помочь с данным заданием?

Comment: смотрите в сторону file_put_contents().